# Get type from variant at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variant

I need to do a typecheck on whether a variant type can hold a type at compile time.

I am converting an enum and a string to a variant, but I want the library to be compatible with a user provided variant (for the types they support). So I have a template parameter `CustomVariant` to represent a variant over a subset of the supported types, `AlphaBeta`, `Gamma`, `Delta`, and `Epsilon`. I would like to return `std::nullopt` if I can't create a valid variant.

```
template <typename CustomVariant>
std::optional<CustomVariant> AsCustomVariant(LargeEnum type, const std::string& name) {
  case LargeEnum::ALPHA:
  case LargeEnum::BETA:
    return ConvertAlphaBeta(name);

  case LargeEnum::GAMMA:
    return ConvertGamma(name);

  case LargeEnum::DELTA:
    return ConvertDelta(name);

  case LargeEnum::EPSILON:
    return ConvertEpsilon(name);

  default:
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

The idea is to use some sort of template magic that can do something like:

```
if (std::type_can_convert<CustomVariant, Gamma>) {
  return ConvertGamma(name);
} else {
  return std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: What is CustomVariant?  Is it a std variant?  Is Gamma a type?  If tha variant hokds a type that can be converted-from the reyurn type of ConvertGamma, is that good enough, or only exact matches?  If the first, what kind of ordering?  Where is your switch statement, it appears to be missing.  Is LargeEnum contiguous?

Comment: The template magic you're looking for is `if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<Gamma, CustomVariant>)`.

Answer (score 7):

With c++17 (I know it's tagged with c++11), this is super easy - you don't even have to really do anything:

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // this works, as expected
    if constexpr(is_constructible_v<variant<int>, double>) {
        // this will run
    }

    // this is fine - it just won't happen, 
    if constexpr(is_constructible_v<variant<int>, string>) {
        // this won't run
    } else {
        // this will run
    }
    // but obviously the assignment of a string into that variant doesn't work...
    variant<int> vi="asdf"s;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/I-wJU1

Answer (score 2):

First I'd do this:

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<class...Ts>using one_tag_of=std::variant<tag_t<Ts>...>;

using which_type=one_tag_of<AlphaBeta, Gamma, Delta /* etc */>;

which_type GetType(LargeEnum e){
  switch (e){
    case LargeEnum::Alpha:
    case LargeEnum::Beta: return tag<AlphaBeta>;
    // etc
  }
}
```

Now we do this:

```
template <typename CustomVariant>
std::optional<CustomVariant> AsCustomVariant(LargeEnum type, const std::string& name) {
  auto which = GetType(type);
  return std::visit( [&name](auto tag)->std::optional<CustomVariant>{
    using type=typename decltype(tag)::type;
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible<CustomVariant, type>{})
      return MakeFromString( tag, name );
    return std::nullopt;
  }, which );
}
```

this leaves `MakeFromString`.

Write overloads like this:

```
inline Delta MakeFromString(tag_t<Delta>, std::string const& name){ return ConvertDelta(name); }
```

note, not specializations.  Just overloads.